# Node.js different behavior response

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  response.write("Hey! Ho!");

  setTimeout(function () {
    response.write("Let's Go!");
  }, 1000);

   setTimeout(function () {
    response.write("Let's Go!");
  }, 2000);

   setTimeout(function () {
    response.write("Let's Go!");
    response.end();
  }, 3000);

}).listen(8080);
```

When I run the following and I try accessing `localhost:8080` on my browser the following happens:

```
 Hey! Ho! 
 // After one second 
 Let's Go! 
 // After one second 
 Let's Go! 
 // After one second 
 Let's Go!
```

When I run it on the terminal with `curl http://localhost:8080` I get:

```
// Wait's for 3 seconds
Hey! Ho! Let's Go! Let's Go! Let's Go!
```

Why don't I get the same behavior on the terminal as the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `curl` waits for the entire response body to complete prior to displaying it by default (this is called buffering). Your browser however, will stream it, rendering the page as it receives it.

You can disable buffering in curl by using the `-N` or `--no-buffer` flag:

```
$ curl -N http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct, although @mscdex answered first, because yours is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `curl -N http://localhost:8080`. `-N` disables output buffering.